# Automatically Move Cell Reference Once Column Over When A Condition Is Met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Table 1:
For example: A subcontractor will be entering the date of an update in row 1 and the average linear feet installed per day since the last update in row 2.

Table 2: I have the entire date range of the project on row 4 (as the x-axis of the progress graph). In row 5, the y-axis of the graph, I need to show the feet-per-day for every day of the update period (i.e. “25” every day from the start until 5-May), and then automatically change to the next period’s feet-per-day when it gets to the next update period.

Is there a function for the formula in row 5 that will advance the feet-per-day reference cell (row 2) to the next cell over when the date in row 4 falls into the next update range (row 1)?

I’ve made versions that just use IF, OR, AND statements that include every cell in the range in the formula…but for very short ranges. I’m changing the requirements and now the range could be hundreds of cells long, so I can’t make a formula like “if G5<B1 put A2; if H5<B1 put A2…” if I have to go out to column FF.

I hope this is clear. Please let me know if I should clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be able to do this with INDEX and SUMIF. I don't 100% follow the example, but something like:

```
=INDEX(A:A,SUMIF(G5:FF5,">"&B1)+1)
```